# Showing that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_{i} - a_{j})^2 = 2n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i} - \bar{a})^2$

Tags: anova, variance, ancova

I wish to show $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_{i} - a_{j})^2 = 2n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i} - \bar{a})^2$ for any numbers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$.

I assume the first step $+\bar{a}$ and $-\bar{a}$ in the first equation, to get $(a_{i} - \bar{a})^2$ in the end. But, I can't get it to the second equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint, for any numbers the sum of the mean deviations is zero, i.e.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(a_i - \bar{a} \right) = 0 $$

Recall also that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left(a_i - \bar{a} \right)^2 =  \sum_{j=1}^n \left(a_j - \bar{a} \right)^2 $$

With these in mind, you should be able to reach the sum on the RHS.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I don't know why my mind didn't think of that first part. Thanks!